# Radix Sort for Floats

Tags: c, casting, bit-shift, radix-sort

I want to sort floats in C with radix. Below is the code I have. However, my output is not correct. For example, if I run the code with 3.1, -5, and 1 my sorted values are printed as 3.000000, -5.000000, and 1.000000.

I know to cast correctly from a float to an int back to a float, I need to apply the following logic but I am not sure how to integrate this into rfloat() because I tried and am getting many errors.

How would I be able to correctly apply a bitwise radix sort to floats?

```
float x = 3.1, *y; 
    int *a; 
    
    a = (int *)&x; 
    y = (float *)a; 

    printf("%f",*y);
```

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

void rs(unsigned int *a, int c) {
    int i;
    int m = a[0];
    int bt = 0;
    unsigned int *b = malloc(0 * sizeof(int));

    for (i = 0; i < c; i++) {
        if (a[i] > m)
            m = a[i]; 
    }

    while((m>>bt) > 0){ 
        int buck[2] = { 0 };

        for (i = 0; i < c; i++) { 
            buck[(a[i]>>bt)&1]++;
        }

        for (i = 1; i < 2; i++) { 
            buck[i] += buck[i-1];
        }

        for (i = c-1; i >= 0; i--) { 
            b[--buck[(a[i]>>bt)&1]] = a[i]; 
        }

        for (i = 0; i < c; i++) {
            a[i] = b[i]; 
        }
        bt++;
    }
    free(b); 
}

void rfloat(float *arr, int c) {
    int d[c]; 
    int i; 
    
    for(i = 0; i < c; i++){
        d[i] = (int)arr[i];
    }
    
    rs(d, c);
    
    for(i = 0; i < c; i++){
        arr[i] = (float)d[i]; 
    }
    
}

int main() {
    int size;  
    int i; 
    float* arr = malloc(0* sizeof(float)); 
    
    printf("Size: "); 
    scanf("%d", &size); 
    
    for (int i = 0; i < size; i++){
        printf("Values: ");
        scanf("%f", &arr[i]); 
    }
    
    rfloat(arr, size); 
    
    printf("Sorted: ");
    for (i = 0; i < size; i++){
        printf("%f ", arr[i]);
    }
    free(arr); 
}
```

Comment: What do you think this does: `malloc(0 * sizeof(int));`? The return value will either be 0 or a pointer which cannot be dereferenced.

Comment: OT: when compiling, always enable the warnings, then fix those warnings. ( for `gcc`, at a minimum use: `-Wall -Wextra -Wconversion -pedantic -std=gnu11` )  Note: other compilers use different options to achieve the same results.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Positive** floats sort in the same order as they would if you would sort their bit pattern as unsigned integers. Negative floats do not, they sort in the **reverse** order than if you would sort their bit pattern. Furthermore, negative floats sort *after* the positive ones if you would sort on their bit pattern, because their top bit is set.

So what do we do? We do a transform. We flip all the other bits if the top bit is set (making negative numbers sort correctly between themselves), and we always flip the top bit (to make negative and positive numbers sort correctly). Then after sorting we reverse the transformation.

No rounding needed!

```
void rfloat(float* arr, size_t size) {
    assert(sizeof(unsigned) == sizeof(float) && sizeof(float) == 4);
    unsigned* d = malloc(size * sizeof(unsigned));
    
    for (size_t i = 0; i < size; i++) {
        // Interpret float as 32-bit unsigned.
        d[i] = *(unsigned*) &(arr[i]);

        // Flip all except top if top bit is set.
        d[i] ^= (((unsigned) (((int) d[i]) >> 31)) >> 1);

        // Flip top bit.
        d[i] ^= (1u << 31);
    }
    
    rs(d, size);
    
    // Inverse transform.
    for (size_t i = 0; i < size; i++) {
        d[i] ^= (1u << 31);
        d[i] ^= (((unsigned) (((int) d[i]) >> 31)) >> 1);
        arr[i] = *(float*) &(d[i]);
    }
    
    free(d);
}
```

---

Note that your code still doesn't work after this. Your radix sort routine has issues. But that is for another question, if you can't figure it out yourself.

Comment: Is there a way for me to preserve the decimal places? For example, if I input -123456.1234567 as one of the values to sort, I want it to stay as -123456.1234567. Currently, it is printing as -123456.125000. I tried printf(".7%f ", arr[i]); but I think the loss is happening in the rfloat() when converting the values.

Comment: @mathisfun1234 Nope, that's the fundamental limit of `float`. You'd need to use `double` (which can also use the above trick but you'd need to use 64 bit integers and change some constants).